# Canon T2i - Pop-up flash does not pop up

Tags: canon-550d, popup-flash

I was shooting at the skate park with friends and when I needed my internal flash, it didn't want to pop-up.
I have a Canon Eos Rebel T2i. It's always in Manual and when I press the flash button nothing happens.

Is there a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [My D3100 takes longer exposure shots instead of using the flash](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/42034/my-d3100-takes-longer-exposure-shots-instead-of-using-the-flash)

Comment: I don't believe this to be a duplicate - the OP explicitly states that he's pressing the flash button which (on the 550D anyway) should make the flash pop up if you're in any of the "creative zone" modes, and the poster also states they're in manual mode.

Comment: http://tutorialgeek.blogspot.com/2013/02/how-to-fix-popup-flash-on-your-camera.html

Comment: Do you hear any sound or get an error when pressing the button? My canon (not a T2i) makes three audible attempts and then gives an error. If you hear nothing and it can't be manually opened while pressing the button, it sounds like there may be a problem with the button.

Answer (score 2):

It may be due to the latch not releasing properly. Try lifting the cover of the flash while pressing the flash button.

Comment: Nope :/ still stuck

Comment: Hmmm, check this link, maybe it's of some help: https://www.flickr.com/photos/dougpardee/133066175/